# function that returns the result of calling json_decode return a string

Tags: php

I am working on an application written in php 7.1.33 and for some unknown reason a strange behavior is occurring.

A function that returns the result of calling `json_decode` is returning a `string`. The code is similar to the following

```
public function post($url, array $body = [])
{
    try
    {
        $client = $this->getClient();
        $response = $client->request('POST', $url);

        $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        $output = json_decode($content);

        return $content;
    }
    catch (ClientException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

For some reason the call to the `post` function returns a string.

In fact, the problem is more complex for me because if you notice in this section

```
$content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
$output = json_decode($content);

return $content;
```

I must do it like this because if I try this way it returns `null`

```
return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

The processed `json` is similar to this

```
'{
  "id": 5895018,
  "first_name": "Zu",
  "last_name": "Mr",
  "email": "zu.mr@bbking.com",
  "phone": null,
  "birthdate": null,
  "postcode": null,
  "address": null,
  "city": null,
  "country": null,
  "gender": null,
  "virtual_money": "0.0",
  "money": "0.0",
  "global_refundable_money": "0.0",
  "balances": { "60402": 0.0, "60403": 0.0, "60464": 0.0, "60463": 0.0 },
  "locale": "en",
  "anonymous": false,
  "refundable": true,
  "family_id": null,
  "family_owner": false,
  "gtags": [],
  "tickets": [],
  "orders": []
}'
```

I have tried in my local that has php 7.4.9 to reproduce the scenario but the result is as expected

```
function simple_test() {
    $json = '{"name": "ada", "last_name": "wong", "email": "ada.wong@umbrella.com"}';

    return json_decode($json);
}

$output = simple_test();

var_dump($output);
```

Output is

```
class stdClass#1 (3) {                                                                                                                                                
  public $name =>                                                                                                                                                     
  string(3) "ada"                                                                                                            
  public $last_name =>                                                                                                                                                
  string(4) "wong"                                                                                                                                                    
  public $email =>                                                                                                                                                    
  string(21) "ada.wong@umbrella.com"
}
```

What worries me is that moving this to production will cause a conflict

Thanks in advance for any ideas

Comment: if you call json_decode() with a string expression, it will return a string, ex: json_decode("abc") -> result "abc", maybe thats what happen

Comment: @AndangSudrajat (+1) is right if in fact your example "json" itself is enclosed in single quotes, as appears to be the case from the sample you included.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `$content` that contains the return value of `$response->getBody()->getContents()`. You should return `$output` instead.

```
$content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
$output = json_decode($content);

return $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try convert same as :

```
$json= '{
  "id": 5895018,
  "first_name": "Zu",
  "last_name": "Mr",
  "email": "zu.mr@bbking.com",
  "phone": null,
  "birthdate": null,
  "postcode": null,
  "address": null,
  "city": null,
  "country": null,
  "gender": null,
  "virtual_money": "0.0",
  "money": "0.0",
  "global_refundable_money": "0.0",
  "balances": { "60402": 0.0, "60403": 0.0, "60464": 0.0, "60463": 0.0 },
  "locale": "en",
  "anonymous": false,
  "refundable": true,
  "family_id": null,
  "family_owner": false,
  "gtags": [],
  "tickets": [],
  "orders": []
}';
$object = (object)$json;

$result  = json_decode($object->scalar);
```

[Link example](https://onlinephp.io?s=bZLrasIwFMe_F_oOpQgqOOk2FTd3e4G9wMYoaZLWaHJSctlwsndf0gRswG_n_P4nJ-f29Nrv-zybGKpN8VxMz3lWFCUj5WOx3j6sq9vtYiAtU9rUgAR1Svlhy4A5GtF3FSkViHFPfu1SqLemOTLolliKqPd7Cf4FWM4DaZgye4JMSnupDZYkhYgQRbVOGGbmlAJpwaiUdRQIVQn6dt9axGvh6vHBZbWsYo1XUMdl44IVbS0Q1HB67Z2LQICpr-9clJtqVd050-mL4N2Pvc0q8aJW_MXhSoz4MFkKMTsCCSchrU_fIq5pwJeSHDfKRtwiwfipHrZ5aTpS-QPDNEZpOoM6n_nzK_iG4SM1YyKVG2EAefY33Tk4kc2BYn88s2DNh2NyUp71ioGp1eygJdSE-l3OYvzNi3bdITWf7_4B&v=7.1.33)